# WooCommerce: trigger event after change of variation

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, product-variations

We use Woocommerce to sell colorboxes.
Mostly the variable-product option is chosen.

We added a modal dialog with a color palette, where the customer can chose a color from.
This is next to the common dropdown of woocommerce.

The problem is that when I pass the right SlugValue to the dropdown (after it gets chosen from palette), then the value in the dropdown is correct, but the event that need to be fired to publish the price doens't works.

I already tried to fire the `onchange` event of the dropdown, but nothing happend.

Can anybody tell me, which event needs to be triggered, and how?

Answer (score 109):

In case anyone stumbles across this in the future:
WooCommerce provides triggers throughout the add-to-cart-variation.js which allows you to hook into change events for the website. You can find all of them available in that file, but one which will likely help most in this case can be used as such

```
$( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
    // Fires whenever variation selects are changed
} );

$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) {
    // Fired when the user selects all the required dropdowns / attributes
    // and a final variation is selected / shown
} );
```

Where the trigger you want to hook into is the first argument inside `.on()`. Here's a few below to get you started:

`woocommerce_variation_select_change` Fires when the select is changed.

`show_variation` is fired when it finds a variation, and will actually pass you the variation object that is found so you can get direct access to the price without having to filter through the selects manually.

You can sift through and find the rest [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js).

Comment: I absolutely cannot get the 2nd event to fire for products with a single variation. The first one runs fine though.

Comment: Hello, sorry to "re-open" this, but I'm having trouble listening to the very first event.
Setup: there's a <select> with all the available options inside. Woocommerce's js then goes through the options and removes unavailable options. I need to listen to that event, which occurs on page load.

This is because I'm customizing the select with select2.js, therefore I need to instantiate select2 *after* Woocommerce has eliminated all unavailable <option>s. Any hints? I tried pretty much every event I found in Woocommerce's JS.

Comment: I would hook into the `wc_variation_form` event and try to do your select2 setup there. That should make sure that it's initialized and ready to go. I'm not sure if select2 continues to watch the original select to see if there are modifications made to it or not, so you *might* need to hook into `woocommerce_update_variation_values` and fire something that would update those values if they are not automatically.

Comment: Nice Solution, was not able to find this solution from hours.

Comment: Pointing in the right direction, but not a direct solution to the question asked. This code says which events are fired on manual select, but not how to fire them.

Comment: @Adal You're correct. Seems I misread a part of that when I wrote this answer a few years ago. I was searching for the answer to my question, and this result came up first and figured I would share. Sent an upvote your way!

Comment: To manually trigger the listener that changes the price shown, I found the correct event to dispatch on line 337 of "https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js".  The event to dispatch is 'check_variations' & should be dispatched against the form

Comment: This needs to be hooked after document ready, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: How would I know which element fired it? Because with the first code, I get the old variation entry and not the new one... Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with vanilla JS? For instance using ```addEventListener()```?

Comment: Thank you. Js `change` event on form element is better or `woocommerce_variation_select_change` ?

Answer (score 9):

This code performs the exact functionality requested in the initial question:

```
$('#WC_variation_drop_down_ID').trigger('change');
```

Change '#WC_variation_drop_down_ID' to the actual ID of the field you changed with jQuery.

Here is a more complete solution that includes setting the field as well as triggering the WooCommerce variation selection (based on array of radio button field classes):

```
var fields = ['.gchoice_4_11_0', '.gchoice_4_11_1', '.gchoice_4_4_0', '.gchoice_4_4_1'];
for ( var i = fields.length; i--; ) {
    $('#gravity_form_wrapper_ID').on('click', fields[i], function() {
        $('#WC_variation_drop_down_ID').val( $(this).children('input').val() ).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

Solution inspired by this post on [setting WooCommerce Variation Fields](https://onethingsimple.com/2015/11/woocommerce-single-products-with-variations-synchronizing-drop-downs/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `$('#WC_variation_drop_down_ID').trigger('change');` does exactly what I intended.
My usecase: I have the normal WC variation menu. Additionally, I create a copy of that menu in a model-viewer instance where the user can select different variations of a 3d model. Both menus change each other and your hint causes the price to update when chosing an option in the 3d-model-variation-menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which variation has been selected.

You can look in the file: `add-to-cart-variation.js` and find that this function also gives you the variation data:

```
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) { }
```

And if you know your variation ID (you can find it by hoovering your variation in backend or by inspection this object when selecting your variation), then you can do:

```
$( ".single_variation_wrap" ).on( "show_variation", function ( event, variation ) { 
  if( variation.variation_id === your_variation_id ) {
    // Do stuff when this variation has been selected 
  }
});
```

I needed to show some additional information when one variation was selected, and this helped me. It is maybe a bit off topic, but this is the discussion I found when searching for this.

Mostly from this [page](https://sarathlal.com/get-variation-product-data-on-selecting-variation-options-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 1):

if anyone comes here like me to find the answer, I will provide a clarification in this.

We have a problem implementing the change function because we need to know the price of variation selected but 'woocommerce_variation_select_change' we got the price from previous variation.

So if you want to get the price of variation after change finish, you have to use 'woocommerce_variation_has_changed' jQuery function.

Example:

`jQuery('#select_attribute_of_variation').on('woocommerce_variation_has_changed', function(){
    // do your magic here...
 })`

Answer (score 0):

I also want a solution that my javascript is only working on 1st variation.
The code is given below

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'script');
function script()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            jQuery('#woocommerce-product-data').on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function () {
                jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce_variation').each(function () {
                    jQuery("#dp").keydown(function () {
                        var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;
                        var dp = document.getElementById("dp").value;
                        console.log(dp);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    </script>


    <?php

}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33084776)