# Woocommerce - added_to_cart trigger

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the WooCommerce added_to_cart trigger to trigger a popup when adding specific products to cart. So far, I have succeeded with the following:

```
jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function() {
        alert("testing!");
    });
```

This shows an alert box when any product is added to cart. However, i would like the alert to only show up for specific categories. But how can I check which category the product added to cart belongs to?

The source for adding to cart is here:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js

And the trigger in question in this:

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ fragments, cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );
```

Answer (score 9):

So I ran into this exact issue as well, and the fix is quite simple.

Your function is actually correct, it just needs to be wrapped in a `.ready()` function.

Your code would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        alert("testing!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the default WooCommerce html structure, this should be of use to you.

I have tested it by running it through Chrome's console on the Storefront demo page, found here: http://demo2.woothemes.com/storefront/shop/. It will display an alert message only when a 'radios' product is added to the basket, it finds the category from the classes on the parent `<li>` for the product.

```
$ = jQuery;
var lastCategory;

$('body').on('added_to_cart',function() {
    if(lastCategory === 'radios'){
        alert('a radio was added!');
    }
});

$('.add_to_cart_button').on('click',function() {
    lastCategory = $(this).closest('li').attr('class').split('product-cat-')[1].split(' ')[0];
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get it to work :-( Cant I get it from the added_to_cart somehow?

Comment: Have you tried running the above code through the console on the Storefront demo? And then again for your webpage? Does it not work on both, or just on yours? A link to the page would be handy, so I can see the HTML.

Comment: I can't get it to work on my own website. However, your suggestion gave me a nod in the right direction, and I ended up giving the needed products a data attribute called popup when they are supposed to make an alert box. Now the following kode kinda works: `var popup;
jQuery('.add_to_cart_button').click(function() {
 popup = jQuery(this).attr('popup');
});

jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function() {
if (popup === 'yes') {
 alert(popup); 
 }
});`

Only thing wrong is that I get 3 or 4 alerts.. How can I force it to trigger only once? This is my site: http://tiny.cc/w65c7x

Answer (score -3):

Insert this code in "functions.php" your template

```
add_action('wp_footer','SA_added_to_cart');
function SA_added_to_cart(){?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Ready state
        (function($){

            $( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                        alert("testing!");
            });

        })(jQuery); // "jQuery" Working with WP (added the $ alias as argument)
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. If you give an answer to a question, you have to explain at minima why your answer help and how. 
Anyway, what you suggest doesn't answer the question.