# removed_from_cart not working on Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to use `removed_from_cart` to update the counter when a product is removed from the cart in Woocommerce, but it doesn't work. Woocommerce recently got a major update and I can't read the documentation - has removed_from_cart changed?
What should I do to update the counter after removing a product from the cart? When I add products to the cart, the counter updates correctly. Thanks

header.php

```
<div class="cart">
  <a href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" class="cart-link">
    <img class="mr-2" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/koszyk.svg' ?>">
    <span class="cart-count"><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

app.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
        var cartCount = parseInt($('.cart-count').text());
        cartCount++;
        $('.cart-count').text(cartCount);
    });

    $(document.body).on('removed_from_cart', function() {
        var cartCount = parseInt($('.cart-count').text());
        cartCount--;
        $('.cart-count').text(cartCount);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check if the removed_from_cart event is triggered?

Comment: yes, when I delete the product I can't even catch anything in console.log

Comment: If your site is heavily cached (either server-side or client-side), try clearing the cache. Sometimes, AJAX responses can be cached, causing the counter not to update as expected. Another common issue could be conflicts with other plugins or the theme you're using. Try disabling other plugins temporarily and switching to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: cache deleted, I don't have any plugins installed except woocommerce

Comment: You can try and wrap your function in a `.ready()` function as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39770836/10497022). Or try using [updated_cart_totals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39321178/10497022) together with `removed_from_cart` like this: `$(document.body).on('removed_from_cart updated_cart_totals', function ()` . Or maybe wrap each in its own `jQuery(function($)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052123/10497022).

Comment: In WooCommerce last version 8.6.1 `removed_from_cart` still works perfectly, so there is something else that is making trouble...