# Select variation option with jQuery woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the variation of a woocommerce product in jQuery.

i have this function `changeColorVar(selectbox,color)`

this function should change the color of the current selectbox and update the woocommerce variable price, but it doesn't update the price, here is the function body

```
 function changeColVar(selectbox,color){

    $form = $(".variations_form"); //GETTING THE FORM

    $form.trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_select_focusin' ); //that we've focused in 
    $(selectbox).find( 'option' ).each(function() {
      $(this)
        .prop('selected', $(this).val() == color); //Setting the selectbox value
    });
    $(selectbox).trigger('change'); //Trying to call woocommerce "check_variations" to update price


}
```

aprec any help!

I'm editing the content-product page in woocommerce, 
I'm showing the variations and add to cart button using this

```
 if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                              do_action('woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart');
                             }
                             else {
                                 do_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart');
                             }
```

I'm also displaying a button in the single product page that does changeColVar function.
when I click on this button i want to change one attributes ("#pa_color") to "Red" value automatically, and updating the price.

I found last this answer but I haven't solved my problem.
[WooCommerce: trigger event after change of variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279555/woocommerce-trigger-event-after-change-of-variation)

Comment: Your question code is incomplete (so unclear) and then not answerable. Please note that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i edited my question

Comment: Sorry but it still not testable… How can we reproduce your issue with the provided code and explanations? Nobody can guess things by magic.