# Ajax add to cart button on single product page with custom field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to edit the single product's page add to cart button.
Successfully added a custom ajax call using LoicTheAztec's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793717/ajax-add-to-cart-for-simple-and-variable-products-on-woocommerce-single-products).

Code is working great. However I need to change $product_id in solution's code with product's custom field value named "custom_id".

Tried to parse it via $custom_data variable, something like:

`$cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $custom_data['custom_id'], $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );`

Also tried to call it with another function:

```
function single_product_text_field() {
    global $product;

   // $cus_id = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_id', true );
      $cus_id = $product->get_meta( 'custom_id' );
    
    if ( ! empty($cus_id) )
        return $cus_id;
}
```

Sadly I had no luck. Clicking the button did not proceed the ajax request.
If i replace $product_id with static custom field value, it's working great.

Unfortunately, I am out of ideas. In case you want to share one I would be at least grateful!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, global `$post` page was declared.
so

```
$cus_id = get_post_field('custom_id', $product_id);
```

did the trick!