# Woocommerce Single product Ajax add to cart with custom cart item data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build an "Add to Cart" button using Ajax in WooCommerce. After a few hours of searching here and on Google, my issue is that I'm able to get a `200` status on my call, but nothing is being added to the cart. I would expect the order to be added to the cart with that type of status.

I have the following code in my active child theme's `functions.php`:

```
function add_to_cart() {
  $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
  $quantity = intval($_POST['quantity']);
  $height = sanitize_text_field($_POST['height']);
  $width = sanitize_text_field($_POST['width']);
  $totalArea = sanitize_text_field($_POST['totalArea']);
  $cost = sanitize_text_field($_POST['cost']);
  $numPanels = intval($_POST['numPanels']);
  $enteredHeight = sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredHeight']);
  $enteredWidth = sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredWidth']);

  WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, 0, array(), array('height'=>$height, 'width'=>$width, 'totalArea'=>$totalArea, 'cost'=>$cost, 'numPanels'=>$numPanels, 'enteredHeight'=>$enteredHeight, 'enteredWidth'=>$enteredWidth));

  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');

function enqueue_add_to_cart_script() {
  if(function_exists('is_product') && is_product()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('add_to_cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/add-to-cart-ajax.js');
    wp_localize_script('add_to_cart', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax_nonce')));
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_add_to_cart_script');
```

I also have the following code in the child theme's `js` folder that I created:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ADD_TO_CART = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');
  const URL = wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart' );

  ADD_TO_CART.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ADD_TO_CART.disabled = true;

    const ORDER = {
      action: 'add_to_cart',
      quantity: 1,
      product_id: '123ABC',
      height: '96 in.',
      width: '120 in.',
      totalArea: '80 sq ft',
      cost: '$636.00',
      numPanels: 5,
      enteredHeight: '96 in.',
      enteredWidth: '120 in.',
    };

    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(ORDER),
    })
    .then((response) => console.log('success:', response))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
  });
});
```

The `console.log('order: ', ORDER);` is creating the object as I expect it to be. And the `console.log('success: ', response);` is returning a `200` as I stated earlier.

BUT nothing is getting added to the cart whatsoever. For the life of me, I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong with this. Does anybody see what (probably simple) step I'm missing here?

Here is a quick little "add to cart" button for anyone to test with:

```php
<?php
  function add_to_cart() { ?>
    <button id="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>
<?php }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, we use jQuery (just as WordPress/WooCommerce already do). I have renamed some functions to avoid problems with existing ones (and renamed some other parameters too).

Try the following revisited code:

The button HTML code:

```html
<button class="custom add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

The PHP code:

```php
// Only in single product pages: Enqueue and localize scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_ajax_add_to_cart_scripts');
function enqueue_custom_ajax_add_to_cart_scripts() {
    if( function_exists('is_product') && is_product() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'custom-add-to-cart', 'wc_params_custom', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
            'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('nonce_custom_atc')
        ) );
    }
}

// PHP WP Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_ajax_add_to_cart');
function custom_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    $cart_item_key = null; // Initializing

    if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce_custom_atc')
    && isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0 
    && isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] > 0) {
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(
            intval($_POST['product_id']), 
            intval($_POST['quantity']), 
            0, 
            array(), 
            array(
                'height'        => isset($_POST['height']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['height']) : '', 
                'width'         => isset($_POST['width']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['width']) : '',  
                'totalArea'     => isset($_POST['totalArea']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['totalArea']) : '', 
                'cost'          => isset($_POST['cost']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['cost']) : '', 
                'numPanels'     => isset($_POST['numPanels']) ? intval($_POST['numPanels']) : '', 
                'enteredHeight' => isset($_POST['enteredHeight']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredHeight']) : '',  
                'enteredWidth'  => isset($_POST['enteredWidth']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredWidth']) : '',  
            )
        );
    }
    wp_die( $cart_item_key ? "Cart item key: {$cart_item_key}" : "Error: not added!" );
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your child theme.

The JavaScript code:

```js
jQuery( function($) {
    if (typeof wc_params_custom === 'undefined')
        return false;

    $('.custom.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  wc_params_custom.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action'        :'custom_add_to_cart',
                'nonce'         : wc_params_custom.nonce, // ==> nonce
                'product_id'    : '123', // ==> integer
                'quantity'      : 1,
                'height'        : '96 in.',
                'width'         : '120 in.',
                'totalArea'     : '80 sq ft',
                'cost'          : '$636.00',
                'numPanels'     : 5,
                'enteredHeight' : '96 in.',
                'enteredWidth'  : '120 in.'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Code goes in `js/custom-add-to-cart.js` file inside your child theme folder.

Tested and Works.

Related: [Ajax Add to cart for simple and variable products in WooCommerce single product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793717/ajax-add-to-cart-for-simple-and-variable-products-in-woocommerce-single-product/65802171#65802171)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was finally able to get it working as expected. Now, I just need to add the custom data to the cart page to be done with this.

EDIT: I spoke too soon. The "cost" is a custom amount depending upon customization. The price won't be on the product itself, but calculated in the moment. When I made that change, it stopped adding to the cart. Any ideas?

Comment: As this answer code answer your initial question and works, try to ask a new question with a more complete testable code version, explaining what the problem is.

Comment: I've spent the past several hours trying to figure out my issue without luck. I opened a new question here (if you would be so kind?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275693/add-custom-price-and-other-data-to-woocommerce-cart