# Add Custom Price and Other Data to WooCommerce Cart

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom "Add to Cart" button using Ajax in WooCommerce. I tested it on a product with a set price and it works as expected. However, the products are customizable and the price will be variable depending on how it gets customized. I've looked around and, being new to PHP and WP/WC development, I'm not sure I see anything that helps me.

I currently have the following two functions in the `functions.php` file for my active child theme:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_add_to_cart_scripts');
function enqueue_custom_add_to_cart_scripts() {
  if(function_exists('is_product') && is_product()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_add_to_cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/add-to-cart-ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('custom_add_to_cart', 'wc_params_custom', array(
      'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce_custom_atc')
    ));
  }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
function custom_add_to_cart() {
  $cart_item_key = null;
  
  if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce_custom_atc')
  && isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0
  && isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] > 0) {
    $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(
      intval($_POST['product_id']), 
      intval($_POST['quantity']), 
      0, 
      array(), 
      array(
        'height'=>isset($_POST['height']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['height']) : '', 
        'width'=>isset($_POST['width']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['width']) : '', 
        'totalArea'=>isset($_POST['totalArea']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['totalArea']) : '', 
        'cost'=>isset($_POST['cost']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['cost']) : '', 
        'numPanels'=>isset($_POST['numPanels']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['numPanels']) : '', 
        'enteredHeight'=>isset($_POST['enteredHeight']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredHeight']) : '', 
        'enteredWidth'=>isset($_POST['enteredWidth']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredWidth']) : ''
      )
    );
  }

  wp_die($cart_item_key ? "Cart item key: {$cart_item_key}" : "Error: not added!");
}
```

My JS file looks like this:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    if (typeof wc_params_custom === 'undefined')
        return false;

    const PANEL_WIDTH = 24;

    let height = $('.height).val();
    let width = $('.width).val();
    let totalArea = ((height / 12) * (width / 12)).toFixed(2);
    let cost = (totalArea * 7.95).toFixed(2);
    let numPanels = width / PANEL_WIDTH;

    $('.custom.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  wc_params_custom.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action'        :'custom_add_to_cart',
                'nonce'         : wc_params_custom.nonce,
                'product_id'    : '123',
                'quantity'      : 1,
                'height'        : `${height} in.`,
                'width'         : `${width} in.`,
                'totalArea'     : `${totalArea} sq ft`,
                'cost'          : `$${cost}`, // changes based upon height & width input
                numPanels,
                // These next two fields take their value from the inputs based upon whether it is inches or feet selected. They are not used for any sort of calculation and are only to be passed to the cart for customer info.
                'enteredHeight' : '8 ft',
                'enteredWidth'  : '10 ft'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code above is triggered by a simple:

```
<input class="height" type="text" />
<input class="width" type="text" />
<button class="custom add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

(EDIT: I added how I gather the dimension inputs and handle the calculations to the two code blocks above.)

Obviously, I can't put that into the product page on the backend, so it has to come from user inputs. I also need it to display on the cart page so the customer can see the correct total. I also need `totalArea`, `numPanels`, `enteredHeight`, and `enteredWidth` to show on the cart as well. I still need `height` and `width` sent through somehow as they go to a production team, but be hidden from the customer. The fields `enteredHeight` and `enteredWidth` are simply to show the customer the dimensions they entered on the customizer page so they don't get confused.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could get this custom data displaying properly, as well as the data that production would need?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I found this post and tried to make it work with my code, but I'm still getting the `Error: not added!` from the `wp_die()`. I think I'm on the right track with it though. [Adding a product to cart with custom info and price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482540/adding-a-product-to-cart-with-custom-info-and-price)

Comment: I asked you to provide a more **complete** code version (ideally with dimensions input fields and price calculations), as with the provided code is not possible to really understand the problem. [Adding a product to cart with custom info and price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482540/adding-a-product-to-cart-with-custom-info-and-price) answer is outdated, but it's the correct way to handle the product calculated price in cart, checkout…

Comment: I have added the dimension inputs and various methods of calculations as requested. I've gone over the answer in that link several times, but still can't figure out how to apply it to my situation. I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Does PANEL_WIDTH is set in the product as custom meta data (custom field), if yes what is the meta key? Does the base cost (7.95) is set in the product as price? If not, where `7.95` is stored?

Comment: PANEL_WIDTH and the price both come through the WordPress Database. Those are the values currently being used. I just placed them as is here to make it easier to work with. I have code in another file that successfully pulls them through should changes ever be made in the DB.

Comment: I sent a connection request as it wouldn't let me send a message for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display some custom cart item data, set the calculated cart item price and will save some custom cart item data as custom order item metadata (displaying that metadata on orders and email notifications.

The HTML code *(with a bit of PHP)*

```
<p class="final-cost">Cost: <span></span></p>
<label for="width"><?php _e('Width'); ?><br>
<input type="text" id="width" name="width" value="" /></label><br>
<label for="height"><?php _e('Height'); ?><br>
<input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="" /></label><br>

<input type="number" name="custom-qty" value="1" style="width:4em;" />
<button class="custom add-to-cart" data-product-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php _e('Add to Cart'); ?></button>
<input type="hidden" name="base-cost" value="<?php echo get_option('apv_price'); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="panel-width" value="<?php echo get_option('apv_panel'); ?>" />
```

The PHP code:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_add_to_cart_scripts');
function enqueue_custom_add_to_cart_scripts() {
    if(function_exists('is_product') && is_product()) {
        // Don't use "add-to-cart-ajax.js" file name as it can interact with WooCommerce (or other plugins) existing file names.
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_add_to_cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_localize_script('custom_add_to_cart', 'wc_params_custom', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce_custom_atc')
        ));
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    $cart_item_key = null;
    
    if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce_custom_atc')
    && isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0
    && isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] > 0 
    && isset($_POST['final_cost']) && $_POST['final_cost'] > 0) {
        $formatted_cost = wc_price(floatval($_POST['final_cost']));
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(
            intval($_POST['product_id']), 
            intval($_POST['quantity']), 
            0, 
            array(), 
            array(
                'height'     => isset($_POST['height']) ?     sanitize_text_field($_POST['height']) : '', 
                'width'      => isset($_POST['width']) ?      sanitize_text_field($_POST['width']) : '', 
                'final_cost' => isset($_POST['final_cost']) ? floatval($_POST['final_cost']) : '', 
                'dim_unit'   => isset($_POST['dim_unit']) ?   esc_attr($_POST['dim_unit']) : '', 
                'num_panels'  => isset($_POST['num_panels']) ? floatval($_POST['num_panels']) : '',
                'total_area'  => isset($_POST['total_area']) ? floatval($_POST['totalArea']) : '', 
                'ent_height' => isset($_POST['ent_height']) ? esc_attr($_POST['ent_height']) : '', 
                'ent_width'  => isset($_POST['ent_width']) ?  esc_attr($_POST['ent_width']) : ''
            )
        );
    }

    wp_die( isset($cart_item_key) && $cart_item_key ? $formatted_cost : "Error: not added!");
}

// Optionally display some custom cart item data in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_cart_item_datat', 90, 2 );
function display_custom_cart_item_datat( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['ent_width']) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => __('Width'),
            'value' => $cart_item['ent_width']
        );
    }
    if( isset($cart_item['ent_height']) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => __('Height'),
            'value' => $cart_item['ent_height']
        );
    }
    if( isset($cart_item['num_panels']) ){
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => __('Panels'),
            'value' => $cart_item['num_panels']
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}


// Set custom calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_calculated_item_price', 20, 1 );
function set_custom_calculated_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') > 1 )
        return;


    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if( isset($cart_item['final_cost']) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval($cart_item['final_cost']) );
        }
    }
}

// Handle mini cart displayed price
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_custom_calculated_item_price', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_calculated_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['final_cost']) ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => floatval($cart_item['final_cost']) ); 

        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        }
        return wc_price( $product_price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}

// Save custom cart item data as order item meta and display it on orders and emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_custom_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset($values['custom_data']['share_owner']) && isset($values['custom_data']['dynamic_amount']) ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['ent_width']) ){
            $item->update_meta_data( 'ent_width', $cart_item['ent_width'] ); 
        }
        if( isset($cart_item['ent_height']) ){
            $item->update_meta_data( 'ent_height', $cart_item['ent_height'] ); 
        }
        if( isset($cart_item['num_panels']) ){
            $item->update_meta_data( 'num_panels', $cart_item['num_panels'] );
        }

        // Displayed only in admin order items: meta_key starting with an underscore
        if( isset($cart_item['total_area']) ){
            $item->update_meta_data( '_total_area', $cart_item['total_area'] );
        }
    }
}

// Add readable "meta key" label name replacement for order item meta data
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'order_item_display_readable_custom_meta_keys', 10, 3 );
function order_item_display_readable_custom_meta_keys( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if( $item->get_type() === 'line_item' ) {
        if( $meta->key === 'ent_width' ) {
            $display_key = __('Width');
        } elseif( $meta->key === 'ent_height' ) {
            $display_key = __('Height');
        } elseif( $meta->key === 'num_panels' ) {
            $display_key = __('Panels');
        } elseif( $meta->key === '_total_area' ) {
            $display_key = __('Total area');
        }
    } 
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

The JavaScript code:

```js
jQuery( function($) {
    const h = 'input#height',
          w = 'input#width',
          baseCost   = $('input[name=base-cost]').val(),
          panelWidth = $('input[name=panel-width]').val();

    var height, width, dimUnit, totalArea, finalCost, numPanels; // Initializing variables

    // Cost calculation and display
    $(document.body).on('input', h+','+w, function() {
        height    = $(h).val();     
        width     = $(w).val();
        dimUnit   = 'ft'; // => Dimension unit (to be replaced with a dynamic value)

        console.log('height: '+height+' | width: '+width);

        if ( height > 0 && width > 0 && dimUnit !== 'undefined' ) {
            // calculations
            totalArea = ((height / 12) * (width / 12)).toFixed(2),
            finalCost = (totalArea * baseCost).toFixed(2),
            numPanels = width / panelWidth;

            console.log('totalArea: '+totalArea+' | finalCost: '+finalCost+' | numPanels: '+numPanels);
            
            $('.final-cost span').html('$'+finalCost); // Display the formatted cost
        }
    });

    if (typeof wc_params_custom === 'undefined')
        return false;
    
    // Ajax add to cart with custom cart item data
    $('.custom.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( height > 0 && width > 0 ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  wc_params_custom.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action'        :'custom_add_to_cart',
                    'nonce'         : wc_params_custom.nonce,
                    'product_id'    : $(this).data('product-id'),
                    'quantity'      : $('input[name=custom-qty]').val(),
                    'height'        : height,
                    'width'         : width,
                    'dim_unit'      : dimUnit,
                    'total_area'    : totalArea+' sq ft',
                    'final_cost'    : finalCost,
                    'num_panels'    : numPanels,
                    'ent_height'    : '8 ft',
                    'ent_width'     : '10 ft',
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh");
                    console.log(response); // returns the formatted price if added to cart
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error); 
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('missing with or height'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Code goes in js/custom-add-to-cart.js file inside your child theme folder.

Comment: In the function associated with the hook `'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item'`, you have the values being added to `$cart_item` despite it not being declared. My VS Code is throwing errors for each one being an unassigned variable. Am I needing to declare it in that function somehow?

Comment: I have updated the function associated to `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` hook, as there was a mistake. I use VScode too, and there are no errors… All this code shows you the way to do things. The PHP Ajax responder function adds multiple cart item custom data. Then from each other function, you can display / save any of that custom data as you need. The calculated price is correctly set, displayed and self passed to the related order item...