# How to add item to Woocommerce cart in self created plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to Wordpress development and I am trying to create a plugin which makes it possible for a user to create a custom image.

I have created the `custom-image` plugin using html, css and javascript. The plugin is shown with a shortcode using this code in `custom-image.php`:

```php
function form_shortcode() {
    this_is_a_function_which_outputs_html();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom-image-shortcode', 'form_shortcode');
```

Below, you can find the current structure of my plugin which is located in `public_html/wp-content/plugins/`:

```
- custom-image
-- css
-- img
-- js
-- custom-image.php
```

The css, img and js folders contains some code for the tool defined in the `custom-image.php`

However, I would like to create a button which would make it possible to add the customised image as a product to the Woocommerce Cart. I have tried the following, but that does not work:

Following code in `custom-image/js/custom-add-to-cart.js`:

```js
jQuery( function($) {
    if (typeof wc_params_custom === 'undefined')
        return false;

    $('.custom.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  wc_params_custom.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action'        :'custom_add_to_cart',
                'nonce'         : wc_params_custom.nonce, // ==> nonce
                'product_id'    : '160', // ==> integer
                'quantity'      : 1,
                'height'        : '96 in.',
                'width'         : '120 in.',
                'totalArea'     : '80 sq ft',
                'cost'          : '$636.00',
                'numPanels'     : 5,
                'enteredHeight' : '96 in.',
                'enteredWidth'  : '120 in.'
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(document.body).trigger("wc_fragment_refresh");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Following code in `admin-ajax.php`:

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_ajax_add_to_cart_scripts');
function enqueue_custom_ajax_add_to_cart_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-add-to-cart', plugins_url('/custom-image/js/') . '/custom-add-to-cart.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'custom-add-to-cart', 'wc_params_custom', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
            'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce('nonce_custom_atc')
        ) );
    
}

// PHP WP Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_ajax_add_to_cart');
function custom_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    $cart_item_key = null; // Initializing

    if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce_custom_atc')
    && isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0 
    && isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] > 0) {
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(
            intval($_POST['product_id']), 
            intval($_POST['quantity']), 
            0, 
            array(), 
            array(
                'height'        => isset($_POST['height']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['height']) : '', 
                'width'         => isset($_POST['width']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['width']) : '',  
                'totalArea'     => isset($_POST['totalArea']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['totalArea']) : '', 
                'cost'          => isset($_POST['cost']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['cost']) : '', 
                'numPanels'     => isset($_POST['numPanels']) ? intval($_POST['numPanels']) : '', 
                'enteredHeight' => isset($_POST['enteredHeight']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredHeight']) : '',  
                'enteredWidth'  => isset($_POST['enteredWidth']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['enteredWidth']) : '',  
            )
        );
    }
    wp_die( $cart_item_key ? "Cart item key: {$cart_item_key}" : "Error: not added!" );
}
```

And a simple button in the `custom-image.php`, so it is shown in the shortcode:

```html
<button class="custom add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

Someone advice? I would like to keep the code in the plugin repository, so it stays maintainable, if its possible.

Comment: You say: *"I have tried the following, but that does not work."*: What does not work? What do you get? What happens? Where are the debugging details? … Note that `ob_start();` is missing in your first function (shortcode). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Nothing happends. The page get reloaded (So I am sure the javascript is not executed). Nothing is added to the cart, no prints in the console, ...
And I would like to move the admin-ajax.php code to a php file in my plugin directory...

Comment: It seems that you mainly took the code from ["Add Custom Price and Other Data to WooCommerce Cart"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275693/add-custom-price-and-other-data-to-woocommerce-cart/77284687#77284687) and you should mention that in your question as it's respectful for the original authors… I have tested this answer code in a plugin (with some minor changes), and it works fine… So there is something else in your code that is making trouble.