# Trigger event after change of variation WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations, add-action

I have a price block for every single product page in the WooCommerce project. Like Cash Price, COD Price, PayPal, Stripe, etc.

[image]

Here what I want is to change this pricing based on the selected variation.
Ex: I have capacities like 32GB, 64GB, 128GB. So, change this price block based on the selected variation.

Therefore I tried to add an action where I can trigger the event when variations were added. But I can't see that action is working. This is my action code to trigger when variation is selected and price changes. But I can't see this alert in firing.

```
function change_pricing_block() {
    ?>
    <script>
    $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
        alert('variation');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_pricing_block' );
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279555/woocommerce-trigger-event-after-change-of-variation

Comment: $ should return error use jQuery( ".variations_form" )